# How to save Vim bg color setting?

Tags: vim

I'm learning Vim for programming on my lubuntu laptop, but the dark blue color for comments makes my eyes melt. It looks better when using `:set background=dark` but it does not seem to remember this between sessions. I am a bit scared of changing the syncolor.vim file. Is there another way to make Vim remember this setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: add that line (without the colon) to your `~/.vimrc` file

```
set background=dark
```

Yup, just edit the vi settings file with vi. Create it if it doesn't exist. You can also address syntax coloring individually. Add this to .vimrc:

```
hi Comment  term=none  ctermfg=magenta  guifg=Magenta
```

Vim also supports entire, ridiculously complex suites of syntax color schemes. This comes down to picking a scheme you like from, say [vimninjas.com](http://www.vimninjas.com/2012/08/26/10-vim-color-schemes-you-need-to-own/) or [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=&script_type=color+scheme&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search), dropping the color scheme file (molokai.vim, say) into the `~/.vim/colors` directory that you made just now, and adding this to .vimrc:

```
colorscheme molokai
```

Other programmer-friendly .vimrc settings I think you'll like:

```
set scrolloff=3
set incsearch
set hlsearch
hi IncSearch ctermfg=blue ctermbg=white
```

Those affect searching, and adjust the view when you move near the top or bottom edge. Add that last line BTW, only if you don't set a color scheme. Yet another thing: I usually find the answer to tricky Vim topics somewhere on [vim.wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki).